# I have error to log in to phpmyadmin page

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am going to make a website using wordpress. I install WAMP new version and 
Then i goto phpmyadmin page. it shows me login page. but we cannot make account there. I am new to this .
[image]

could you tell me how to log into this page... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good ol' phpmyadmin...good and stable.

First time user:

```
User: root
Password:
```

First time installed root hasn´t got password, but you should put one (security reasons)

You can change password following this steps:
Open phpMyAdmin and select the SQL tab. Then type this command:

```
 SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('your_root_password');
```

Also change to this line in config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Cheers to @flowfree, for this answer